# my own directive is not working AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I try to create my directiv. When I make the same code on start angularjs is stopped.

```
demo
```

https://codepen.io/Turqus/pen/yPPmbG?editors=1011

Could someone explain me whats wrong is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to put the first letter of the directives name in lower case as the error in the console told you ( F12 in any browser, then go to console tab ) :

**error log : "Directive/Component name 'MyExample' is invalid. The first character must be a lowercase letter"**

```
    (function(){

  angular
    .module('App', [])
    .controller('ExampleCtrl', ExampleCtrl);

  function ExampleCtrl() {
    var vm = this;
    vm.name = "yo"; 
  };

})();


(function(){

  angular
    .module('App')
    .directive('myExample', MyExample);    // <----------------- HER

    function MyExample() {
      var directive = {
        restrict: 'E',
        template: '<div>one more time</div>',
        controller: 'MyController',
        controllerAs: 'vm' 
      };
      return directive;
    }

    function MyController() {

    }

})();
```